# When you trust a bluetooth device, where is the config file that stores the trust?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspbian-buster

Lets say I run this command

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# paired-devices
[raspberrypi]# paired-devices
Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX MyDevice
[raspberrypi]# trust XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Trusted: yes
Changing XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX trust succeeded
```

Where is the actual file that stores the list of trusted devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do something like `$ sudo grep -Ri trust /var/lib/bluetooth` you will see some information.

This does come with a big warning that it is not the intended way to gain access to the information. The intent is that it will be accessed with the BlueZ API's documented at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

And the official examples are at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test

Typically this means using the D-Bus bindings. From the command line you can get a list of everything BlueZ knows about with:

```
busctl call org.bluez / org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager GetManagedObjects
```

In a language like python, it would be:

```py
import pydbus

bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
mngr = bus.get('org.bluez', '/')

mngd_objs = mngr.GetManagedObjects()

for path in mngd_objs:
    device_info = mngd_objs[path].get('org.bluez.Device1')
    if device_info:
        print(f'Device: {device_info.get("Address")} is Trusted={device_info.get("Trusted")}')
```

To extend this to answer the question below about how to remove any trusted devices...

This is controlled by the adapter interface and the [RemoveDevice](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/org.bluez.Adapter.rst#n60) method. We need to know the D-Bus path for the Adapter object. There are many ways you can be find this information, using `busctl tree org.bluez` on the command line may be the quickest. The path is typically `/org/bluez/hci0` and will prepend all your devices. With that assumption, you can extend the above example to delete trusted devices as follows:

```py
import pydbus

bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
mngr = bus.get('org.bluez', '/')

mngd_objs = mngr.GetManagedObjects()
dongle = bus.get('org.bluez', '/org/bluez/hci0')

for path in mngd_objs:
    device_info = mngd_objs[path].get('org.bluez.Device1')
    if device_info:
        trusted = device_info.get('Trusted')
        if trusted:
            print(f'Removing Device: {device_info.get("Address")}') 
            dongle.RemoveDevice(path)
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I guess i could jump to my second question. how would I able to remove the devices? The idea is, after every boot, a cron script runs and removes all trusted devices. How easy would that be?

Comment: I've extended the answer to cover this question. Typically it would be better to update your question or open a new question rather than ask it in the comments.